# What is the formal or general term for the y-intercept?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Is there a general term for the value at which a function intercepts the vertical axis, in the Cartesian plane?

It seems "$y$-intercept" is used ubiquitously in English, but I'd rather not conflate the concept of a dependent variable with the specific symbol $y$.

In French, the term is "l'ordonée à l'origine" lit: (the value of) "the ordinate at the origin," is there any equivalent in English?

I've tried multiple searches & the usual reference sites, but not found anything.

Comment: You could use "the value at zero."  I expect most of the time that would be understood (in context).

Comment: The value of the dependent variable when the independent variable is $0$, or the *insert dependent variable here*-intercept. Other than what Brian suggested, I am not sure if there are any other commonly used terms.

Comment: Why not "vertical-axis intercept" or just "vertical intercept"? - It does not "*conflate the concept of a dependent variable with the specific symbol *"

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment and the other two above...
You do not need to associate the symbol, "$y$", as a function of $x$. Instead, you could just write $f(x) = \cdots$ or $f(x, y, z, \cdots) = \cdots$, if the function contains multiple variables. This means your vertical axis become the values for $f(x)$ and not "$y$" anymore. Hence, you describe the intercept at the vertical axis, **mathematically**, where the $x = 0$ or similar if your function has more variables. This is the mathematical form of @Brian Tung comment.

Alternatively, if you are really keen on describing the intercept based relative cartesian plane (no variables involved), it may be best to address it as the "**vertical intercept**".